# Php MySQL not displaying all rows

Tags: php, mysql

here is code i am trying to display all data from database...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
print_R($row1);
```

but it is displaying only one row.. I have totally three rows in database ,
if i run the same query in database, it displays all rows..
 i want to display all three rows how to fix this?

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, it's outdated and obsolete. Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're expecting multiple rows you need to loop them using while:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $row1['column_name'];
}
```

Obligatory Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Here is a simple example coming from PDO's counterpart:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name', 'username', 'password'); // simple connection
$query = $con->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC'); // put your query here
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // same concept, you need to fetch them and put them inside the while loop since you're expecting multiple rows
    echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Basically the first answer will work but I urge you to ditch that deprecated API and start using PDO. Don't worry, you won't have shortage of sources in learning this API.

Comment: +1 for the "_Please, don't use mysql_* functions **in new code**._" instead of the widespread for OP's often useless and not very constructive "_mysql_* is deprecated_", which only is the case for new PHP versions, <4% of the servers worldwide.

Answer (score 0):

Try while loop

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to loop ur query,

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
print_R($row1);
```

// wrong one

use mysqli,

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

// Check connection

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

// Perform query

```
      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC");
        $mainarr=array();    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $subarr=array();
        $subarr['key']=$row['your field'];
        array_push($mainarr,$subarr);
    }  
print_r($mainarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**its simple to use mysqli just try the following once**

```
$mysqli   = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$strr     = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC";  // its a good practice to use column name insted of *
$result   = $mysqli->query($strr);
while($arr      = $result->fetch_array())
{
  print_r($arr);
}
```