# php to display all mysql records, shows only one row

Tags: php, mysql

php to display all mysql records, shows only one row. Please can anyone help me with this?

PHP CODE:

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "SELECT vendorID,joint_name,vendor_contact,vendor_name,vendor_place,joint_lat,joint_long,vendor_profile_pic,time_in,time_out,days_in,date FROM vendor ORDER BY vendorID desc ";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result,array(
                "joint_name"=>$res['joint_name'],
                "vendor_contact"=>$res['vendor_contact'],
                "vendor_name"=>$res['vendor_name'],
                "vendor_place"=>$res['vendor_place'],
                "joint_lat"=>$res['joint_lat'],
                "joint_long"=>$res['joint_long'],
                "vendor_profile_pic"=>$res['vendor_profile_pic'],
                "time_in"=>$res['time_in'],
                "Ttime_out"=>$res['time_out'],
                "days_in"=>$res['days_in'],
                "date"=>$res['date']                

         )
         );

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);

"
RESULT:
"
{"result":[{"joint_name":null,"vendor_contact":null,"vendor_name":null,"vendor_place":null,"joint_lat":null,"joint_long":null,"vendor_profile_pic":null,"time_in":null,"Ttime_out":null,"days_in":null,"date":null}]}
```

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_array($r);` inside `while loop`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php MySQL not displaying all rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340523/php-mysql-not-displaying-all-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
            "joint_name"=>$res['joint_name'],
            "vendor_contact"=>$res['vendor_contact'],
            "vendor_name"=>$res['vendor_name'],
            "vendor_place"=>$res['vendor_place'],
            "joint_lat"=>$res['joint_lat'],
            "joint_long"=>$res['joint_long'],
            "vendor_profile_pic"=>$res['vendor_profile_pic'],
            "time_in"=>$res['time_in'],
            "Ttime_out"=>$res['time_out'],
            "days_in"=>$res['days_in'],
            "date"=>$res['date']                

     )
     );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what I have now:

Comment: If my answer helped you please tick as right answer so other can also take benefit of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're executing **mysqli_fetch_array** function only once. Put it in a while loop to fetch as many rows as result-set have.

You can put it into `while` loop to get all the rows from table.

Like this,

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
      array_push($result,array(
                "joint_name"=>$res['joint_name'],
                "vendor_contact"=>$res['vendor_contact'],
                "vendor_name"=>$res['vendor_name'],
                "vendor_place"=>$res['vendor_place'],
                "joint_lat"=>$res['joint_lat'],
                "joint_long"=>$res['joint_long'],
                "vendor_profile_pic"=>$res['vendor_profile_pic'],
                "time_in"=>$res['time_in'],
                "Ttime_out"=>$res['time_out'],
                "days_in"=>$res['days_in'],
                "date"=>$res['date']                

         )
         );
}
```

`$result` will have all the rows from result-set.

> **mysqli_fetch_array()** returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there
>   are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result
>   parameter.

So the while loop stops working as soon as there are no more rows to fetch from result-set.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all results in an array with [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). You also don't need to copy the results manually. Your code then simplifies to:

```
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT vendorID,joint_name,vendor_contact,vendor_name,vendor_place,joint_lat,joint_long,vendor_profile_pic,time_in,time_out,days_in,date FROM vendor ORDER BY vendorID desc ";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo json_encode("result" => mysqli_fetch_all($r));
```

Of course, you should do error checking.

As a side note, you should not let `dbConnect.php` define the global variable `$con`. Better provide a factory function.